# Unity Particle Collider with Particle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Unity
I create two collider effects and want them can have some function while them collider each other . but i don't know how to make two particle collider.
How to make fire and water can collider each and fire will be put out by  water. 
Thank for help!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unity particle system can collide with colliders(objects) in the scene if collision is enebled for particle system.

But particle systems do not collide with each other. Particles have no volume, so it's not really possible.

You cannot use built-in particle system for fire and water and have them collide with each other. However, you can create a custom particle system using actual objects having colliders which can work as you expect.

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysCollisionModule.html)

> **Send Collision Messages**  : Check this to be able to detect particle
>   collisions from scripts by the OnParticleCollision function.

Be careful though. Overdoing collisions and particles is a good way to get performance issues

Be sure to follow the tutorials for particle systems too! 
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/particle-system

Thats the best I can currently do, given you have not supplied any work we can comment on.