# Unity Make 2 Particle Systems Collide

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've done some research and it seems the consensus is that two particle systems can't collide in unity.

Is there a creative work around or solution to have the effect of having two particle systems collide? I want it to behave like two "streams of water" colliding where each stream is a particle emitter. I can't think of a great solution besides making my own particle emitter, but even then it would be hard to mimic Unity's particle system behavior. I feel like there has to be a way to make that effect though.

Any ideas appreciated, thanks

Comment: This may be a duplicate of this question: [Unity Particle Collider with Particle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760688/unity-particle-collider-with-particle)

Comment: Its a similar question but i'm asking for possible work around ideas. That doesn't contain anything besides a "not possible" and an answer that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: "You cannot use built-in particle system for fire and water and have them collide with each other. **However, you can create a custom particle system using actual objects having colliders which can work as you expect**." directly answers your question of "Is there a creative work around or solution to have the effect of having two particle systems collide?"

Comment: "I can't think of a great solution besides making my own particle emitter, but even then it would be hard to mimic Unity's particle system behavior." clearly i already considered that option and am looking for other ones that might help. Im looking for an expanded explanation of how to handle this situation that may have other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `GameObject`--the emitter--that spawns other `GameObject`s--the water particles--that have `Rigidbody`/`Rigidbody2D` and appropriate `Collider` components. The exact components you will need will depend on the shape of the spawned object.

To avoid performance loss related to instantiating and destroying many objects, you may want to use [object pooling](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling) for the water particle `GameObject`s.

In these water particle `GameObject`s you'll want to implement `OnCollisionEnter` or `OnCollisionEnter2D` to handle the interaction between them. You can check for whether the collision is with another water particle inside of `OnCollisionEnter*`, and interact appropriately.